# How to secure port forwarding on AirPort Extreme

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, airport-extreme

I have a small home server to share photos, blog, videos, etc. with family and friends around the US and Western Europe.  Of course I have seen evidence of malicious scanning against my network/server.

I'd like to set up a ruleset to only allow NAT forwarding for a select group of IP address ranges that I trust.  The AirPort Extreme doesn't have this feature.  Do I need to buy a firewall at $400 plus subscriptions, or will a small switch ($150) meet the basic needs?

Comment: Mike, a clarification if you would: Do you only want to allow port translation to occur if the source is a trusted IP?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to spend that much on obtaining a firewall product that offers you granular control over NAT/masquerading.

Some standalone firewall/gateway products that will install on minimal hardware:

- [Sophos UTM](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx) (free for home use)
- [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/) (open source firewall)

You're at most looking for a bare-bones, low-end computer with dual network adapters.